# Can ping over IPv6 but can't reach HTTP

Tags: amazon-ec2, ipv6, ubuntu-16.04, plesk

I've a server running Plesk on Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS EC2.
I've configured the IPv6 as described on [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html), and can `ping6` to the server fine.

My server ubuntu's firewall is disabled, the only firewall is the AWS Security Group, and it allows IPv6 over port 80.

The problem is that when I try to access any of the hosted websites over IPv6 from outside server, it simply don't respond and timeout:

> [ec2-user@ip-172-31-50-91 ~]$ curl --connect-timeout 5 -6
>   https://store.newolders.com curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5001
>   milliseconds

If I do the same from inside the server, it works fine.

Someone can help me? If necessary I can provide more informations, I didn't want to make the question too long! :-)

Comment: The URL in your question works fine for me over IPv6.

Comment: I've just restarted the server, and it's surprisingly working now. -.-' Now I'm looking for the reason of this.